# The product of improper Riemann integrable function and a bounded continuous function

Tags: improper-integrals

Let $f$ be an improper integrable function on an unbounded set $[a,+\infty)$ and $g$ is a bounded continuous function, then I hope to determine whether $fg$ is improper integrable or not?

I think the answer is no, but I fail to find an example. I check the proof of integrable function which uses $(f+g)^2$ and $(f-g)^2$, but we know that this is not true for inproper integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

The improper integral $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot \sin x \,dx =\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x} \,dx $ is divergent.